# Arch Linux audio issues on ROG Zephyrus M16

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, laptop

I got a new ROG Zephyrus M16 recently, and tried to install Arch on it.  Everything went smoothly using the `archinstall` script (using PulseAudio), and I was booted into the GUI no problem.  The problems begin when I try to play audio.

This laptop has 4 speakers in total: 2 mid-range speakers and 2 woofers.  I went to [play the THX Deepnote](https://thx.com/deepnote) and realized that I could not turn the volume down on my bass speakers.  This resulted in a muffled sound, and only at max volume does the audio sound proper (of course it's too loud).

I have looked on the internet to fix this, and a Reddit user pointed me to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906303/volume-control-on-asus-zenbook-3/917257#917257), stating that it worked for them.  However this only seems to have turned off my mid-range speakers entirely, but allowing me to control the volume of my woofers.  I have a total of 3 audio configurations:

```
Analog Stereo  
Analog Surround 2.1 Output  
Analog Surround 4.0 Output
```

Testing each one, I've once again confirmed that my mid-range speakers are turned off.  Going into the "Test Sound" button next to the "Output Device" menu while `Analog Surround 4.0` is selected, I have a total of 4 speakers on the GUI.  Front Left, Front Right, Back Left, Back Right.  Back Left and Back Right work fine, using my woofers.  The front speakers, however do not output any audio.

Analog Surround 2.1 Output setting has Front Left, Front Right, and Subwoofer.  Subwoofer works fine, as it uses my woofers, but again, Front Left and Front Right try to use my mid-range, and have no output.

So, how would I configure this so that my mid-range and subwoofers are constantly at the same volume, while keeping my stereo separation?  Thanks.